# Get count of two column in access 2007

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, count, ms-access-2007

TblAquestion:

```
AQcode(pk)|AQdescribe
---------------------------------
1          do you want to continue?     
2          what ..........?
3          this is a ..........
4          my name is a ali?
```

TblUserResult:

```
ID(pk)|AQcode_fk|Result
-----------------------
100    1         1
101    1         0
102    1         0
103    1         0
104    1         1

105    2         1
106    2         0

107    3         1
108    3         1
109    3         1
110    3         0

111    4         1
```

OutPut:

```
ResultYes is count of result where '1'
ResultNo is count of result where '0'
AQcode|AQdescribe                 |CountResultYes|CountResultNo
---------------------------------------------------------------
1      do you want to continue?    2              3
2      what ..........?            1              1
3      this is a ..........        3              1
4      my name is a ali?           1              0
```

SQL command?

Comment: This isn't a code writing service, please show the effort you've made to solve the problem yourself, including the code you've tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select aqcode,aqdescribe,sum(Cno),sum(Cyes) from
(
select aqcode,aqdescribe,'0' as Cno,count(result) as Cyes
from TblAquestion aq,TblUserResult r
where aq.aqcode=r.aqcode and r.result='1'
group by aqcode,aqdescribe
Union
select aqcode,aqdescribe,count(result) as Cno,'0' as Cyes
from TblAquestion aq,TblUserResult r
where aq.aqcode=r.aqcode and r.result='0'
group by aqcode,aqdescribe
)
group by aqcode,aqdescribe
```

Comment: Now that Juergen has fixed his code, you should reconsider that solution.  It is a much simpler way to do the calculation.

Answer (score 2):

```
select q.AQcode, q.AQdescribe, 
       sum(IIF(r.Result = 1, 1, 0)) as CountResultYes,
       sum(IIF(r.Result = 0, 1, 0)) as CountResultNo
from TblAquestion q
left join TblUserResult r on r.AQcode_fk = q.AQcode
group by q.AQcode, q.AQdescribe
```

Comment: In Access 2007: Error 'when'

Comment: Logical Error: CountResultYes=CountResultNo

Comment: Are you sure you have it exactly like I do?

Comment: @juergend . . . I believe you want `sum()` rather than `count()`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Of course. Silly me.